# How to add third party dll in Tridion for C# TBB?

Tags: c#, xml, html-parsing, tridion

I am creating a C# TBB. 
I have the XML code as shown below.

```
<content>
  <ah>123</ah>
  <ph>456</ph>
  <body>
    <sc>hi</sc>
    <value>aa</value>
    <value>bb</value>
    <value>cc</value>
    <value>dd</value>
    <value>dd</value>
  </body>
  <body>
    <sc>hello</sc>
    <value>ee</value>
    <value>ddff</value>
  </body>
</content>
```

C# TBB code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
XmlTextWriter securboxXmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false));
securboxXmlWriter.Indentation = 4;
securboxXmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();


securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("component");

securboxXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
securboxXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");


securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("content");
securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("wire:wire");
securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("wire:si");

securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("wg:ah");
securboxXmlWriter.WriteElementString("text", package.GetValue("Component.ah"));
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

securboxXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("wg:ph");
securboxXmlWriter.WriteElementString("nlt", package.GetValue("Component.ph"));
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
securboxXmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
securboxXmlWriter.Flush();
securboxXmlWriter.Close();



Item output = package.GetByName("Output");

if (output != null)
{
package.Remove(output);
}

package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Xml, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())));
}
```

In the XML code "body" tag is occured multiple times. I need to extract the each and every "body" tag content. For that purpose I am using HTML agility pack. To make it work in the C# TBB, How to add the HTML agility pack DLL to the Tridion system? And also please  provide a sample code snippet in html agility to loop through the body tags.

If HTML Agility is not going to work with C# TBB then please suggest me a way how to get the "body" tag content?

Thanks in advance.Early response is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you can also use [ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) to merge together your third party DLL and your TBB assembly into one single one you can then upload into Tridion.

Comment: Yes you can, and I have good experiences with that. The only reason why I didn't mention it, is that merging your own DLL with a third-party DLL might easily lead to copyright infringement. As long as you're sure that is not going to be a problem, you could use that approach as well. I'll provide more details in a separate answer.

Comment: I don't think there's a copyright issue. Copyright is about source code. If someone doesn't want their IL used, they shouldn't ship an assembly DLL, because that's effectively shipping the IL. Of course, you could be breaching license conditions, but that's another issue, and I've never seen a condition that bans this technique. On the down side, using ILMerge can cause some nasty side-effects. I recently had an issue with a Tridion hotfix that AFAIK would only ever show up with an ILMerge approach

Answer (score 7):

You will need to place the third party DLL in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). For the sample agility pack code I suggest you ask a separate question for that with a more specific title.

Comment: Remember to put the DLL in the GAC on every content manager and publisher machine.

Answer (score 4):

Using ILMerge saves you the hassle of installing external DLLs in the GAC. Just make sure you do not break any (copyright) laws by merging your code with someone else's.
Technically, it is simple enough to do: after your template DLL has been built, a post-build action merges it with the external DLLs you may need, and creates a new DLL. You can then upload that merged DLL to Tridion.

Example: let's say your template project is called 'MyTemplates' and it has a dependency on ExternalLibraryOne.dll and ExternalLibraryTwo.dll. Here's what you do:

- Download ILMerge from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630 (it's free)
- Inside your templating solution, create a folder called Solution Items and copy ilmerge.exe there.
- Open the properties of your templating project and add the following post-build event:

  "$(SolutionDir)Solution Items\ilmerge"
  /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
  /t:dll /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
  /out:"$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).merged.dll" 
  "$(TargetDir)ExternalLibraryOne.dll" 
  "$(TargetDir)ExternalLibraryTwo.dll" 
  "$(TargetPath)"
- Build your template project. The output folder (bin/Debug or bin/Release) will now contain a file called MyTemplates.merged.dll. You can upload this to Tridion using TcmUploadAssembly.

This is assuming you are using .NET 4 of course.